# finding $f''(x)$ and $f'''(x)$ of problem

Tags: calculus

Below is a problem I am trying to solve.  I know how to do 2nd and third derivatives, but I have no idea how to solve this or even how to type it into wolfram alpha to get a better idea.  Any help would be nice.

$$f(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ \dots + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0$$

Comment: You say you know how to second and third derivatives. Then, given that all the $a$s are constants, what are the derivatives of $x^n$? Of $a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$? What are the derivatives of their sums? And so on. What exactly about this is hard for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you copy the text of your question into the question body rather than link to a jpg.

Anyway, the function is a power sereis, and you differentiate it just like you differentiate any polynomial.

$f(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+\cdots + a_1 x + a_0\\
f'(x) = na_n x^{n-1} + (n-1)a_{n-1} x^{n-2} +\cdots +2a_2x+ a_1\\
f''(x) = (n)(n-1)a_n x^{n-1} + (n-1)(n-2)a_{n-3}+\cdots + 2a_2$